# switch to add-on pop-up window interface selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see usually when we click on add-on icon it creates a "pop-up" or a "window", literally another html file as i evidenced., not embodied in main html. I wonder how to switch from main tab to add-on interface and work on it (like click button etc.) without using pyautogui & image detection: it would be too easy ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about frames. A frame is a part of a web page or browser window which displays content independent of its container, with the ability to load content independently (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_(World_Wide_Web) )

You can switch to another frame with the following command:

```
driver.switch_to.frame()
```

As parameter for the frame() function, you have 3 options: frame index (0,1,2, etc), name (an id that the developer has given to the frame, or webelement (ie a unique element in that frame, which you can find as every other element with:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_...)
```

I hope I helped :)

Comment: It didn't work. I've already looked over frame but they are not the answer just because, as i evidenced, add-on interface windows are literally other html page not embodied in main tab. You can check out by yourself. I was wondering if i can us text detection but i'd rather prefer no: it's not the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to click add-on icon on Chrome just using Selenium. Actually, I don't think chromedriver has provided some methods to click on the chrome toolbar, so maybe you can't write codes to do it.

But, there is another way that works.

- Right-click on the add-on icon
- Select the last option `Manage extensions` on the list, a new tab opens which has url like this `chrome://extensions/?id=cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb`.
- Or, Select `Options` on the list, a new tab opens, url like this `chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/options.html`.

[image]

In other words, all of the Chrome extensions configuration pages are actually HTML pages. So you can open the configuration page directly, and click button or do other actions you want.

```java
extensionManagePage = "chrome://extensions/?id=cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb";
driver.get(extensionManagePage);

// or

extensionOptionsPage = "chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/options.html";
driver.get(extensionOptionsPage);

// click button etc.
```

Comment: i use pyautogui image detection to click on extension icon. i tried what you said but it's not right: "Manage Extension" or "Options" page is not add-on interface page!, you can try by yourself. When i click on add-on icon i create a html page called "chrome://extensions/fgddmllnllkalaagkghckoinaemmogpe/html/popup.html" as you can see in the photo. i tried to do `driver.get("chrome://extensions/fgddmllnllkalaagkghckoinaemmogpe/html/popup.html")` but it didn't work :(

Comment: take a look at the third photo

Comment: This is a general solution, but if the HTML page of the extension does not provide the button you want to click, it will not work. Sorry to say that I have no idea how to solve this problem anymore.